Ubuntu 23.10 installer won't make EXT4 partition
I downloaded Ubuntu 23.10 to install instead of Kubuntu last lts (I don't remember the number, 22.04 lts?)
I boot Ubuntu and open the installer, in partition making, I can't make an ext4 partition and so I can't install Ubuntu. Is this a bug in installer or something else?

Do you have available disk space (disk space not part of an existing partition)?
